# Не открывается папка без index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, smarty, index

не открываются ссылки без index.php

- //site.com/stackoverflow <- нужно так но не работает
- //site.com/stackoverflow/index.php <- а так работает

  **движок Smarty**

когда пытаешься открыть вот так

- //site.com/stackoverflow

то сразу идет перенаправление на главную

- //site.com

в htaccess
добавлял 
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

но это не помогло.

```
DirectorySlash Off
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
AddDefaultCharset utf-8


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Вы лучше весь .htaccess добавьте в свой вопрос.

Comment: @Visman добавил

Comment: После `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` добавьте строку `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` и вероятнее всего это `DirectorySlash Off` уберите.

Comment: @Visman Спасибо большое все сработало)

Answer (score 0):

//site.com/stackoverflow/ - слэш в конце добавьте и все будет норм

Comment: неа все равно переадрисация